# Register assembly types as self and as specific interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm trying to register types as self and as one interface.
When I add `As<ICustomScreenDef>` I cannot access concrete types any more. However if I use `AsImplementedInterfaces()` accessing concrete type works again.
Example:

```
public class ScreenDef : IScreenDef {}
public class MyScreen : ScreenDef, ICustomScreenDef {}
public class ScreenGroup 
{
   public ScreenGroup(MyScreen myScreen, IEnumerable<ICustomScreenDef> customScreenDefs){}
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(screensAssembly).AssignableTo<IScreenDef>().
        OnActivating(e => {
            IScreenDef screenDef = ((IScreenDef)e.Instance);
            screenDef.Init();
        })     
        .OnActivated(
            e => {
                ...
            }
        ).AsSelf().As<ICustomScreenDef>().InstancePerDependency();
```

With this code ScreenGroup can't be instantiated because myScreen is missing.
If I change
`AsSelf().As<ICustomScreenDef>()` to `AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces()`
everything works. How can I make this work without using `AsImplementedInterfaces()`?

I hope example captures potential problem since I simplified it.

Comment: Looks like there is no problem in your code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/TJXkeL. I was able to resolve `ScreenGroup` and also checked that unrelated interfaces are not registered.

Comment: So, autofac is supposed to work this way? I don't know if this is a bug but it's counterintuitive for sure.

Comment: yes, as I understand it, this is a normal scenario for Autofac - filter classes then register them in any combination of interfaces/implementations as you wish.